# Docker compose apache not working

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a container using docker compose. I already did it using normal docker commands and it works, but when I do the same using docker compose it did not work as expected.

I compile the image using docker compose build command:

```
docker-compose build php
```

and use that image for both docker and docker-compose commands.

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v /navicu docker_php
docker-compose up php
```

I allays change the port of one of the container so they never collapse. For example: port 80 on docker and 800 on docker-compose.

The problem is that no matter what I do, the docker-compose container is not working as expected. It doesn't let connections on the localhost (it shows a 500 error). On the other hand the docker container allows the connection and show the page as expected.

Here is the docker-compose.yml:

```
php:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  volumes:
   - ./navicu:/navicu
```

PD: the Dockerfile use a php-apache official image and add a vhost.conf file.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're trying to connect to the host (the one running the docker images) or to the docker image itself?

Comment: I tried both host. It is the same since I bind the port of the host to the port of the container. For example if I curl localhost on the host and on the container (the one that come from docker run) it works but when I do the same on the other container (the one that come from docker-compose) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker run` is not equivalent to the compose file.  If you try

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v $PWD/navicu:/navicu docker_php
```

it would be the same, and I expect you'll see the same 500 error.

The equivalent compose volumes would be

```
volumes:
    - /navicu
```

I believe the reason you're getting a 500 error is because you're replacing the container contents at `/navicu` with the files in the host directory, which are probably not correct, or are missing things.